# protection of downloadable file

Tags: download, upload, password-protection, protected

here's my situation:

I have a paint like tool

I want users of the tool to be able to download their creation

I don't want the user to be able to read or open the file

The user needs to upload the same image file to another tool

My problem is i can't make the first tool and third one work in unisson so users definitely need to first click download to then click upload on the other third party tool.

Does this seem possible to any of you? To have a way to protect the downloadable file so that the only option is to upload it to the 2nd tool ?

I hope this was clear enough

Thanks for your help in these dark times, cheers :)

Comment: Your question is actually super vague. Could you please provide us with some code and information about your current setup. For example, the tech. stack.

Comment: There is currently no code or setup of any sort, that's why im asking this question kind of, if it can't be done, there's no need to start basically. And i am not a coder myself therefore i will contract someone to do it once i know it is feasable.

Comment: The file will be a png or jpeg image if that changes something.

Answer (score 0):

There is no "secure" way. Because we're talking about protection, we will not discuss semi-secure ways.

I see only these options:

- Encrypt the file. The other service need the encryption key. It needs to be known before or service a tells it service b in the background (without the client)
- Send the file directly from service a to service b.
- Service b is pulling the data from service a. You transfer-url could be transmitted via the client, if service a is checking the source IP (so only service b is able to download the file from service a).

Comment: You're welcome. If you like my answer, please mark it as an accepted answer and/or vote it.

Comment: ok thank you for your answer :)
the problem is i'm pretty sure none of those 3 will be possible.
you said "we will not discuss semi-secure ways"... but in reality what i need rather than true protection, is more of a small incentive for regular users not to keep the file and do other stuff with it.

Comment: i'm wondering then if you can tell me what are the "semi secure ways" in your opinion. as i said it's really more of an incentive not to use the file without using the 3rd party tool and upload it there. ( let's be honest more than half the people using a computer don't even know you can put a password on an pdf so it doesnt need to be fancy encryptions of anykind) :) :) Happy 420

Comment: For that, you didn't provided enough information. How are they downloaded? manually from the user, or downloaded via WebRequest within software? Is it a desktop app or a browser client? How to upload it to service b? Manually by user or via software? Via Post/Reqeust File Upload? Questions over questions. you need to provide more background information.

Comment: i see yes. Well what i can say is everything is manual. the download will be manual (the user will click the download button on the webapp), and the upload will also be manual. the upload will work the same exact way it does when i want for example to change and upload a new profile picture to my stackoverflaw profile.